# Image inside menu tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using this javascript to make a div with 3 tabs; http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/ (maybe it's easier to see the css code there instead of copying it all here?)

Anyway, I want to use a image inside of the tab instead of the H2 heading, which it uses by default. Is that possible?

```
<div class="tabber">

 <div class="tabbertab">
   <h2>Tab 1 <img src doesn't work here></h2>
  <p>Tab 1 content.</p>
 </div>


 <div class="tabbertab">
  <h2>Tab 2</h2>
  <p>Tab 2 content.</p>
 </div>


 <div class="tabbertab">
  <h2>Tab 3</h2>
  <p>Tab 3 content.</p>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="tabber">

 <div class="tabbertab">
     <h2>Tab 1 <img src="http://slembassyusa.org/downloads/Flag_of_Sri_Lanka.png" width=100 height=20 /></h2>
  <p>Tab 1 content.</p>
 </div>


 <div class="tabbertab">
  <h2>Tab 2</h2>
  <p>Tab 2 content.</p>
 </div>


 <div class="tabbertab">
  <h2>Tab 3</h2>
  <p>Tab 3 content.</p>
 </div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/Zasmj/)
[image]

Comment: It doesn't work in combination with the js file; http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/tabber.js

For some reason it only uses h2 as tab.

Comment: See the screenshot i have added

Comment: Sorry, maybe my explanation wasn't clear. I meant to use a image in the tab itself, the part that you click on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tiny bit of additional js/jQuery code, something in this direction maybe:

```
$(".tabbernav a").each(function(i){
    var $img = $("div.tabbertab:nth-child("+(i+2)+") h2 img")
    if($img.length > 0) $(this).html($img);
});
```

that will grab the image from your `h2` tag and place it into the tab instead of the heading text.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zasmj/3/)

Hope this helps you in the right direction!

Comment: That is exactly what I'm going for, but for some reason, when I copy your code it doesn't work. Do I have to do something with the CSS? Because I can't see that in the jsfiddle.

Comment: in the jsfiddle (external resources) I link to the pluggins webpage's (from your link you provided) [`example.css`](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/example.css) and their [`tabber.js`](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/tabber.js) code. You also need to use [jquery](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery). Hope this works now ^_^

Comment: I don't get it, It works perfectly in jsfiddle, but when I copy it all to a HTML file the images don't show. :(

Comment: But does tabber work as expected? Where are you placing my little js code? You need to call it only after the tabber function is called, so that it finds the tabs, that tabber creates.

Comment: I got the images to work by downloading the source code of http://jsfiddle.net/Zasmj/3/show/, but now the tabs don't work anymore..

Comment: I didn't change anything, I saved that webpage from the source code of your jsfiddle, and the tabs stop working.

Comment: What about trying it [from here](http://newtpond.com/test/tabber-test.html)? If you run it locally, make sure you call jquery with `http://` so that the browser looks for it online. Other than that ... I can not see why it wouldn't work. Good luck!